# "from a country that they are not from"

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

I am rewording this sentence:

> Many people claim to be from a place that they have not been to.

This sounds perfectly fine to me but when I try and pare it down:

> Many people claim to be from a place that they are not from.

This reads grammatical but awkward. Do the followings work?

> Many people claim to be from a place where they are not from.
> Many people claim to be from a place that they are not.
> Many people claim to be from a place where they are not.

Is there a way to make it work and make it idiomatic sounding as well?

**Note:** As is always the case with my questions, I do not need "clever rewrites". I could come up with any number of sentences like "Many people claim to be from a place that they can't legitimately call home." This question is about keeping the basic frame of the sentence and making something awkward work.

Comment: *a place that they have not been to* is ***not*** the same thing as *a place that they are not from*. Someone can ***go*** to many different places / countries over a lifetime (for varying amounts of time), but idiomatically we usually assume a person ***comes from*** only one country (their *native* country, where they were born, and for which they hold citizenship).

Comment: Many people claim to be from ***somewhere other than their true homeland.***

Comment: I appreciate your comments pointing that out. I'm actually fairly clear on the distinction. My question, as suggested by the tags, is really a mental exercise about relative clauses/pronouns, for my own benefit. I would like to see if there's a way to use a relative clause, keep the structure that I had in mind, and make the sentence work, a task that I have failed.

Comment: I've downvoted for the request not to consider "clever rewrites".  The point is that you as the one asking the question, don't know if it can be made to work.  As such, by asking for "no rewrites" you change this from a good question to a silly game.

Comment: I'd say *He claims to be from a place **which** he is not [from]*  and *He claims to be from a place **from which** he is not* are both "syntactically valid", as are most if not all of your suggestions. But none of them are anywhere near as natural as my ***somewhere other than*** suggestion. If you just want to prove a point re the basic *construction*, though, why not use a slightly different example sentence? I see no problem with ***He claimed to own something [that] he didn't***, for example (but I'd prefer ***He falsely claimed to own something*** :)

Comment: Grammatically fine, semantically different.

Comment: @JamesK Here is the rationale behind this question and a handful other questions I've posted: On the contrary, I would contend the point is exactly to avoid the prospect of certain users turning my question into a scoring game. As has happened a few times with my questions and as is very common on SE, some users see a question and rush to submit an answer without careful consideration, without even trying to understand what the question is really about. They don't want to take a minute to examine the q and see what the asker understands and what is being asked. For them it's a rep reaping game

Comment: @JamesK I don't think the q is "a silly game." I could've worded it better and I'm gladly open to suggestions to make the q clearer. But it bothers me that in a lot of cases I've seen many users see a q, especially on sites like ELL and ELU, say something endlessly arrogant and condescending: "Oh you just have to learn that!" or give some basic ESL level rewrites, hoping to get some upvotes. I'm disinclined to name and shame but I could, as it definitely happened to several of my ELL/ELU q. That's the reason I said I wasn't looking for "rewrites". It is not and should not be a rep reaping game

Comment: The question is really about explaining how it's possible - and it is - to have a preposition hanging off the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 3):

There is the problem that you have changed the meaning of the sentence. There are dozens of places where I’ve been to. There is only one place where I am from.

And the last sentence “ Many people claim to be from a place where they are not.” would mean for example a person who is not in Italy right now claiming they are from Italy.